# Assign list name to dataframe list element

Tags: r

I have a list of lists of dataframes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

a <- list(first = data.frame(x=runif(1), y=runif(1)),
          second = data.frame(x=runif(5), y=runif(5)))
b <- list(first = data.frame(x=runif(1), y=runif(1)),
          second = data.frame(x=runif(5), y=runif(5)))
a <- a %>% set_names(1:length(a))
b <- b %>% set_names(1:length(b))
c <- list(a, b)
c <- c %>% set_names(1:length(c))
```

I want to assign the two levels of list names as new columns to the dataframe, and then bind them into one dataframe. The desired output is something like:

```
  x    y   name1   name2
.23  .43       1       1
.23  .43       1       2
.23  .43       2       1
.23  .43       2       2
```

Where the values of x and y are not the point. I am struggling with this as lapply does not access the name of the element of the list.

Thanks.

Comment: The code produced errors on my end after the lines containing `%>%` . (I have `dplyr` loaded). I presume you use a package like `magrittr`? may be good to know for those who want to replicate the question.

Comment: Don't use `c` as a name for your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
res <- melt(c) %>%
             group_by(variable) %>% 
             mutate(indx=row_number()) %>%
             spread(variable, value) %>% 
             ungroup() %>% 
             select(-indx)
```